# Implement a forward function using universal reference

Tags: c++, c++11

The implementation of `std::forward` in VS2013 is

```
template<class _Ty> inline
    _Ty&& forward(typename remove_reference<_Ty>::type& _Arg)
    {   // forward an lvalue
    return (static_cast<_Ty&&>(_Arg));
    }

template<class _Ty> inline
    _Ty&& forward(typename remove_reference<_Ty>::type&& _Arg) _NOEXCEPT
    {   // forward anything
    static_assert(!is_lvalue_reference<_Ty>::value, "bad forward call");
    return (static_cast<_Ty&&>(_Arg));
    }
```

One version for lvalue reference, one version for rvalue reference. Why not just use a universal reference for both rvalue and lvalue reference:

```
template <typename T, typename U>
T&& Forward(U&& arg) {
  return static_cast<T&&>(arg);
}
```

Comment: FWIW, the standard mandates the overloads in §20.2.3.

Answer (score 4):

Your version is not standard-compliant, as `std::forward` is is required to not compile when called with on an rvalue if `T` is an l-value reference. From `[forward]`:

```
template <class T> T&& forward(typename remove_reference<T>::type& t) noexcept;
template <class T> T&& forward(typename remove_reference<T>::type&& t) noexcept;
```

> 2 Returns: `static_cast<T&&>(t)`.
>
> 3 if the second form is instantiated with an lvalue reference type, the program is ill-formed.

`std::forward` is defined in this way to ensure that (some) misuses of `std::forward` do not compile. See [n2951](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2009/n2951.html) for more discussion (although even n2951 does not use this exact form).

Comment: If I always correctly use the forward function, is there any difference between my implementation and standard implementation?

Comment: @QingYun you can use your own function but that means "I wrote a function which, in some cases, could crash the program". If you can make sure you'll NEVER encounter those cases I believe it's fine. But since the standard protects you from those and the checks are done at compile-time.. I really don't see the point..

Comment: Actually, I want to write a `forwardNth` function to forward specific element in a parameter pack. It won't be used in situations other than just forward universal reference argument.

Answer (score 3):

I'm expanding a bit on the problem you've pointed out here.

Your version would introduce a **reference-dangling** case if you attempt to bind a newly created rvalue to a l-value reference.

As Mankarse linked, the [n2951](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2009/n2951.html) paper cites this case and, by simplifying it a bit, you can summarize it with the following code

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

template <typename T, typename U>
T&& Forward(U&& arg) {
  return static_cast<T&&>(arg);
}

class Container
{
    int data_;
public:
    explicit Container(int data = 1) // Set the data variable
        : data_(data) {}
    ~Container() {data_ = -1;} // When destructed, first set the data to -1

    void test()
    {
        if (data_ <= 0)
            std::cout << "OPS! A is destructed!\n";
        else
            std::cout << "A = " << data_ << '\n';
    }
};

// This class has a reference to the data object
class Reference_To_Container_Wrapper
{
    const Container& a_;
public:
    explicit Reference_To_Container_Wrapper(const Container& a) : a_(a) {}

    // (I) This line causes problems! This "Container" returned will be destroyed and cause troubles!
    const Container get() const {return a_;} // Build a new Container out of the reference and return it
};

template <class T>
struct ReferenceContainer
{
    T should_be_valid_lvalue_ref; 

    template <class U> // U = Reference_To_Container_Wrapper
        ReferenceContainer(U&& u) : 
         // We store a l-value reference to a container, but the container is from line (I)
         // and thus will soon get destroyed and we'll have a dangling reference
         should_be_valid_lvalue_ref(Forward<T>(std::move(u).get())) {}
};

int main() {

    Container a(42); // This lives happily with perfect valid data
    ReferenceContainer<const Container&> rc( (Reference_To_Container_Wrapper(a)) ); // Parenthesis necessary otherwise most vexing parse will think this is a function pointer..
    // rc now has a dangling reference
    Container newContainer = rc.should_be_valid_lvalue_ref; // From reference to Container
    newContainer.test();

    return 0;
}
```

which outputs "OPS! A is destructed!"

if you just add a "&" in the line

```
const Container& get() const {return a_;}
```

the above works just fine.

http://ideone.com/SyUXss

Comment: Also: vertical scrolling :(

Comment: You confused me by leaving out the SFINAE check :D The `ReferenceContainer` ctor should only take rvalues.

Comment: @dyp sorry :D I wanted to make this easier to read (it's already a bit hard at first sight)